# hidden attribute on custom elements with shadow DOM rendering in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, polymer, polymer-1.0, web-component, shadow-dom

When using shadow DOM rendering in polymer instead of shady DOM I've noticed that custom elements can not be hidden with the global attribute `hidden`.

This only seems to affect Chrome since it the elements gets hidden in both Safari and Firefox (IE unknown).

Here is a example for the Chrome browser using `iron-icon`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Demo</title>

  <script src="https://polygit.org/components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.js"></script>

  <script>
    // Setup Polymer options
    window.Polymer = {
      dom: 'shadow'
    };
  </script>

  <link rel="import" href="https://polygit.org/components/polymer/polymer.html">
  <link rel="import" href="https://polygit.org/components/iron-icon/iron-icon.html">
  <link rel="import" href="https://polygit.org/components/iron-icons/iron-icons.html">
</head>
<body>
  <my-app></my-app>
  <dom-module id="my-app">
    <template>
      <p>
        hidden: <iron-icon icon="bug-report" hidden></iron-icon>
      </p>
      <p>
        visible: <iron-icon icon="check"></iron-icon>
      </p>
    </template>
    <script>
      Polymer({is: 'my-app'});
    </script>
  </dom-module>
</body>
</html>
```

https://jsbin.com/xetiboboya/4/edit?html,output

When changing `window.Polymer.dom` to `shady` it correctly hides the `iron-icon` element.

Explicitly setting a style for iron-icon with a hidden attribute works as well.

```
iron-icon[hidden] {
  display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because Polymer adds, in the Shadow DOM of `<iron-icon>`, a `<style>` element with a CSS rule that overrides the `hidden` attribute.

```
<style>
   :host { 
       display: inline-flex;
   }
</style>
```

This rule is itself overridden by the one you added.

```js
I1.attachShadow( { mode: 'open' } )
  .innerHTML = `icon 1
<style>
    :host { 
        display: inline-flex ;
        color: red ;
    }
</style>`

I2.attachShadow( { mode: 'open' } )
  .innerHTML = `icon 2
<style>
    :host { 
        display: inline-flex ;
        color: red ;
    }
</style>`
```

```css
#I1[hidden] {
    display: none ;
}
```

```html
<iron-icon id=I1 hidden></iron-icon>
<iron-icon id=I2 hidden></iron-icon>
```

**Update**

Also, because of the `shadow` mode, Shadow DOM is created for your `<my-app>` elements that blocks the global `[hidden] { display: none !important; }` CSS rule, added by Polymer `iron-flex-layout.html` file.

`shadow` mode actually applies only in browsers implementing Shadow DOM (Chrome, Opera), that's why the rendering is different on Firefox or Safari.

Look at the amended JSBin : https://jsbin.com/qolegopago/edit?html,output